# Deploy Nodejs to Heroku: Error with babel (es6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, babeljs

I've got this error from the heroku console when deploying the app.
It work on local but fail to deploy.

```
SyntaxError: /tmp/build_4b397c70/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/docs/gatsby-browser.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (7:10):
  5 |
  6 | export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
> 7 |   return <Layout {...props} >{element}</Layout>
    |          ^
  8 | }
  9 |
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:810:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:803:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9982:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11367:22)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10941:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10921:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10899:23)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10756:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10730:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/tmp/build_4b397c70/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10693:21) {
  loc: Position { line: 7, column: 9 },
  pos: 209,
  missingPlugin: [ 'jsx', 'flow', 'typescript' ],
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR'
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxx",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./index.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-babel",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
    "build-babel": "babel . --out-dir dist --ignore node_modules"
  },
  "author": "tiavina-mika",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.1.0",
    "express-validation": "^3.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
  ]
}
```

I added @babel/preset-react to the 'presets' section of the babel config and still got the same error

NOTE: it's a simple nodejs server api not a react one, but the error suggest the use of preset-react.

Comment: I think you're missing a babel preset-react config here which is might be used by Heroku

"to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation" this line i mean
 
refer to the docs here to see what it might be https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problems with Heroku when generate `build` directory. You change directory input to other (for example `src`).

I share you my builder and start script:

```json
  "prebuild": "rm -rf ./dist",
  "build": "babel ./src -d ./dist --ignore node_modules,test",
  "prestart": "npm run build",
  "start": "pm2-runtime start ./dist/index.js"
```